# Mouse/touchpad cursor disappearing on HP pavilion running ubuntu 20.04 or 21.10

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, hp, cursor

I am new to ubuntu, I have been running 20.04 on VM(on Acer aspire 5) for a year now with no problems. I recently got a new laptop, HP Pavilion with windows 10, and decided to dual boot it with ubuntu, during the installation process, the cursor disappeared so i used the keyboard to complete it.
After installation and logging on, I still have the same problem, the cursor disappears after about a second once i log in. It works though as it highlights things when i move my finger across the touchpad.
I have been looking everywhere on the internet for the past few days for a solution to this to no avail, getting frustrated out here, please help.

The hardware specs are as follow:

Microprocessor
Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 (1.0 GHz base frequency, up to 3.6 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology, 6 MB cache, 4 cores)
Chipset
Intel® Integrated SoC
Memory, standard
12 GB DDR4-2666 SDRAM (1 x 4 GB, 1 x 8 GB)
Video graphics
Intel® UHD Graphics
Integrated
Hard drive
512 GB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add hardware specifications, namely the graphics. "HP Pavilion" is meaningless because there are hundreds of different models under that "marque" spanning decades.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you. I edited the question to add the specs to it.

Comment: Make sure the system is fully updated. It should be running the very latest kernel available for the release (currently 5.13.x). Check with `uname -a`.

Comment: I'm running the latest kernel, 5.13.0-30-generic. This version has been working fine on my VM fine for about a year now. I tried installing ubuntu 21 also, and I had the same problem. The cursor is visible for only a second or two and then it disappears.

Comment: What happens with the virtual hardware in a VM is irrelevant for the problem in question.

Comment: Yes, I am just pointing that out just to show that the installation media is fine. This is a new laptop I got a few days ago that I am trying to use linux on permanently. The issue is really frustrating me as I cant seem to get much than without the pointer.